# Vue routers cannot be import while using export, using iview-admin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, iview

I first use this

```js
export const paperRoute = {
  path: '/paper/:id',
  name: 'paper',
  component: () => import('@/view/paper/paper-info'),
  meta: {
    title: 'papaer',
    hideInMenu: true
  }
}
```

in `src/router/paper-routers.js` and use it in `src/router/routers.js` by

```js
import paperRoute from './paper-routers'
```

And when I get into 'localhost:8080/paper/1', nothing was there, even other pages that were loaded correctly turn into nothing.

After I change the `paper-routers.js` into

```js
export default {
  path: '/paper/:id',
  name: 'paper',
  component: () => import('@/view/paper/paper-info'),
  meta: {
    title: 'paper',
    hideInMenu: true
  }
}
```

The page was correctly loaded.
I am confused, what's the difference between these two styles,

- `export const paperRoute`
- `export default`

when I use `import paperRoute from 'src/router/paper-routers.js'`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, my fault.

when using export, it should be

```js
import { ... } form ...
```

I forgot the brace.